# Web MVC design cause facebook php sdk failed to read param code in address bar

Tags: php, facebook, .htaccess

As a student, I'm trying to learn more deeper in MVC framework, so I refer the tutorials from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdtiltiRHWGXVHXX09fxXDi-DqInchFD) to build a simple MVC framework.

The problem occurs when facebook return the  param "code" from authorization,

```
http://domain.com/user/fbregister/?code=[long_code_here]#_=_
```

Facebook cannot getAccessToken from helper since .htaccess had been changed

```
$helper->getAccessToken() return null
```

I try to print_r the related $_SERVER and this is the results :

```
REQUEST_URI = /user/fbregister/?code=[long_code_here]&state=[long_code_here]

QUERY_STRING = url=user/fbregister/
```

Obviously, param code doesn't exists in the return URL...

I found what's wrong in my code, but I dunno how to fixed it, maybe change

```
getCurrentUrl() in UrlDetectionInterface
```

I cannot figure out how, please help me...

PS : I know using pure Facebook JS SDK or mixed with PHP can solved this question, but I hope I can learn more in php